# Why my device is not supported by my game on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have a device with Android  2.1 (API-7),
it supports bluetooth, WiFi, but there is NO GSM and 3G.

I have a game.
Google play said that the game is not supported by my device.

But the game WAS VISIBLE on Google Play before I added permissions for Admob banners.
Mistery.

I played with manifest.
If I erase Bluetooth permissions, the game is visible on the Google Play.

The manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="mypackage1..."
      android:versionCode="13"
      android:versionName="4.5">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13"  android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
              android:label="@string/select_device"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity2"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"

  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    <service android:name=".BillingService" />
    <receiver android:name=".BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name=
"com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED"   />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>
```

So what is the problem with my first game? 
My device is tablet "Inch U7s".
Permissions for my  game APK on Google are as follows:

```
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, 
android.permission.BLUETOOTH, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
com.android.vending.BILLING, 
Functions: android.hardware.bluetooth, android.hardware.touchscreen
API: 4-17+
Screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL: all
Platforms: armeabi-v7a, armeabi
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what Google Play is using for filtering, and exactly which device you have? To check the features go to the developer console, open the app page, click on the `APK Files` tab and click the more link under the active apk.

Comment: Ok. I added that info to the end of my message. But where I can find filtering info? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many permissions imply a hardware requirement by default. For instance, if you ask for camera permission the app will require the camera by default. You must specifically set that feature as not required.

Bluetooth shouldn't be a problem since your APK targets API 4+. Maybe it's related to the in-app billing.

Try running "aapt dump badging myapp.apk" and see which uses-feature lines it lists.

Comment: The program was visible on Google play, when I built it for Android 2.1 with bluetooth, in-app billing and licensing. After I start to build the app for Android 3.2 and added Admob ads the problem appeared that my app is not visible on Google Play on my device. But the app works okay if I upload it via USB. As I said, if I exclude bluetooth permissions in manifest, then the app is visible on Google Play again (but I need bluetooth permission!!!)

Comment: "aapt dump badging myapp.apk" just show me the permissions. They are visible on Google site too. Permissions are correct, but suddenly my device does not support bluetooth. But it DOES support bluetooth. Dead end.